# Determine conjugative start row in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.3, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to determine conjugative start row in PostgreSQL

I have table name emp having two columns id(integer) and entry_date(date).
Records like this

```
ID  |  entry_date 
----+-------------
1   |  2018-05-03 
5   |  2018-06-10 
6   |  2018-06-11 
1   |  2018-07-13 
5   |  2018-07-14 
5   |  2018-07-15 
5   |  2018-07-16 
5   |  2018-07-17
```

now I want to find out start conjugative record `(5, '2018-07-14')` and end Record `(5, '2018-07-17')`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: no there are two separate columns ID and entry_date   not store the values with those # delimiters

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select id, min(entry_date) as start_date, max(entry_date) as end_date
from (
  select id, 
         entry_date, 
         entry_date - (row_number() over(partition by id order by entry_date))::int as grp
  from the_table
) t
group by id, grp
having max(entry_date) - min(entry_date) > 1
order by id, grp
```

The expression `entry_date - (row_number() over(partition by id order by entry_date))::int` creates a single DATE value for all "groups" that are consecutive. So the inner query returns the following result (based on your sample data):

```
id | entry_date | grp       
---+------------+-----------
 1 | 2018-05-03 | 2018-05-02
 1 | 2018-07-13 | 2018-07-11
 5 | 2018-06-10 | 2018-06-09
 5 | 2018-07-14 | 2018-07-12
 5 | 2018-07-15 | 2018-07-12
 5 | 2018-07-16 | 2018-07-12
 5 | 2018-07-17 | 2018-07-12
 6 | 2018-06-11 | 2018-06-10
```

By grouping the result on that date (`grp`) we keep those dates together as a single group. The min and max then define the start and end of the consecutive list of values. The having clause then leaves only those where the range is greater than one day.

Which then returns:

```
id | start_date | end_date  
---+------------+-----------
 5 | 2018-07-14 | 2018-07-17
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c55a3b87621ef77ea9728b81700c1fee)

Comment: i have table having customer appointment date and id. now i want to find out appointment date 
    is business date or holiday like saturday and sunday .

    i want to find out how many customers visits on business day and holiday using  postgresql.

    table name is customers_details having two columns id integer,appoinment_date date.